# (Си) использована неинициализированная локальная переменная

Tags: c

Bозникает ошибка с 3 переменными. Cам код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    char** name;
    float* ch;
    float* sum;
    int n, k, i, j, l;
    char** list;
    char tmp[20];
    int* reit;
    printf("Введи длину списка: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    name = (char**)malloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    ch = (float*)malloc(n, sizeof(float));
    printf("Введи список: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", tmp);
        name[i] = (char*)malloc(strlen(tmp) + 2, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(name[i], tmp);
        printf("Введи характеристику: ");
        scanf("%f", ch[i]);
    }
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        l = -1;
        j = 0;
        while ((l == -1) && (j < k))
        {
            if (strcmp(name[i], list[j]) == 0)
            {
                l = j;
            } j++;
        }
        if (l == -1)
        {
            strcpy(list[k], name[i]);
            reit[k] = 1;
            sum[k] = ch[i];
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            reit[l]++;
            sum[l] += ch[i];
        }
    }
    printf("Список без повторений с рейтингами и характеристиками:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        printf("\n %s  %d  %f", list[i], reit[i], sum[i]);
    }
}
```

ошибки:

- использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "list"
  `if (strcmp(name[i], list[j]) == 0)`
- использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "reit"
  `reit[k] = 1;`
- использована неинициализированная локальная переменная "sum"
  `sum[k] = ch[i];`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с этим разобраться.Спасибо.

Comment: Ну так они и в самом деле не инициализированы... Вот? например, вы ни разу не присвоили `list` никакое значение — с чем вы сравниваете `name[i]` в `strcmp(name[i], list[j])`? Как исправить? Дать корректные значения. Какие? А как узнать, что должна делать ваша программа? Чтоб просто компилировалось — можно их обнулять. Только вот потом вы будете спрашивать, почему программа не работает...

Comment: `scanf("%f", &ch[i]);`

Comment: ошибок очень много. сначала уберите отключение предупреждений, и они вам помогут.

Comment: Вы объявили несколько указателей. Они показывают в фактически случайные места. Чтобы указатели стали показывать в какую-то область памяти, в которой можно что-то сохранять, эту область памяти надо выделить, то есть вызвать функцию malloc() и присвоить указателю её результат. Альтернативный вариант — сразу объявлять статический массив, то есть не char **, а char[100][500].